# Transforming format of a list

Tags: python

I have the following list:

```
[[('a', 'b'), 0], [('a', 'c'), 1], [('b', 'c'), 1]]
```

Is it possible to turn the elements into sets, i.e. something like

```
[(('a', 'b'), 0), (('a', 'c'), 1), (('b', 'c'), 1)]
```

Apologies if I have described this wrong - I am not too great with the language

Comment: Try `l = [((a, b), c) for [(a, b), c] in l]`

Comment: `map(tuple, lst)`

Comment: @Jan tuples can be used as set elements, or keys of a dictionary. A list can't do that.

Comment: You can make it by using `map` and `lambda` function:

    `my_list = [[('a', 'b'), 0], [('a', 'c'), 1], [('b', 'c'), 1]]
    my_tuple = map(lambda elem: tuple(elem), my_list)
    print(my_tuple)`

Output: 

    `[(('a', 'b'), 0), (('a', 'c'), 1), (('b', 'c'), 1)]`

Comment: @Abe you don't need a `lambda` here. `lambda x: f(x)` is just `f`, so this is `my_tuple = map(tuple, my_list)`

Comment: @AdamSmith oh great, i didn't try it. Thank u.

Answer (score 1):

What you described there is a tuple and you can do it like this:

```
l = [[('a', 'b'), 0], [('a', 'c'), 1], [('b', 'c'), 1]]

t = [tuple(i) for i in l]
```

The output is:

```
[(('a', 'b'), 0), (('a', 'c'), 1), (('b', 'c'), 1)]
```